# Dynamic number of live events

Tags: jquery, tags, scope

I am having problems implementing a dynamic number of .live() events.

There is a loop to determine how many pages to create links for returned from an ajax call.

Basically I get 1 of 3 (-1, 0, [object Object]) results depending on how I pass the number of pages inside the live event.

Here is how it stands now, where it only returns 0 for each live event.  To get -1, I would remove the contractPage declaration and put that in the net.tsn.contract.log function, or [object Object] I would pass page in the live's handler function.

```
for (var page=(contractId['pages']-1); page>=0; page--) {
    $("#jpgLinks").prepend("<span><a href='#' id='jpgLink"+page+"'><img src='img/JPG-Link_con-" + (page+1) + ".png' alt=''><br>Page " + (page+1) + "<\/a><\/span>");
    var contractPage = contractId['contract'] + "-" + page;
    $('#jpgLink'+page).live('click', function() {
        showWorkingDialog();
        net.tsn.contract.log(contractPage, "DOWNLOAD_JPG", '<?php echo $_GET['lead']; ?>');
    });
}
```

Comment: Were are you getting the results (-1, 0, [object Object]) from?

Comment: It depends on how I put use the variable... The explanation was there, but I must have deleted it on accident.

Comment: I don't really understand the explanation.

Comment: I posted the code for the 3 different conditions instead of re writing the paragraph that explained it.  They are all the same block of code but 3 different ways I've tried to get page into .live()

Comment: If you are using jQuery 1.7 or later [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is preferred over the deprecated .live(). Usage is very similar. If you are using an older version back to 1.4.2 [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is preferred to .live().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I see what the problem is here.  You need to make a closure to close the value of `page` for each `live()` event.

Put this function somewhere in your code (before the for loop):

```
function _contractPage(contractPage, page){
    return function(){
        contractPage = contractPage  + "-" + page;
        showWorkingDialog();
        net.tsn.contract.log(contractPage, "DOWNLOAD_JPG", '<?php echo $_GET['lead']; ?>');
    }
}
```

And then change your for loop like so:

```
for (var page=(contractId['pages']-1); page>=0; page--) {
    $("#jpgLinks").prepend("<span><a href='#' id='jpgLink"+page+"'><img src='img/JPG-Link_con-" + (page+1) + ".png' alt=''><br>Page " + (page+1) + "<\/a><\/span>");
    var contractFunc = _contractPage(contractId['contract'], page);
    $('#jpgLink'+page).live('click', contractFunc);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/T8UjA/

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was just reading an article on closure...so F for me on that one!  page still returns as 0 for each live() event.

Comment: @Rocket,  I think your suggestion is on the right track.  Its about time to go for the day, so I will keep playing with it in the morning. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MarkL You need to put `var contractPage = _contractPage(contractId['contract'], page);` inside the live function.

Comment: @Rocket I have tried it in all different places on the page, I get page= -1 each time if the contractPage delare is inside the live function or 0 if it is just before the live function...I must have something else wrong in my script?  I have also tried the constructor first thing in the script and in a couple of different places, but doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Rocket, The reason it is zero is because that is the value of page at the last iteration, so for some reason it changes each live event to point to page 0 (first page).  I reversed the for loop and it now points to only page 2 (third page).  So this leads me to believe you can't declare x amount of live events in a for loop?  That just doesn't make sense tho.

Comment: @Mark: The problem is that the live event is using a variable that you are changing during a loop.  The closure I am trying to make should work, but I guess I did it wrong.

Comment: @Rocket, does $("#jpgLink" + page) always use page's current value? IOW $("#jpgLink"+page) never becomes static after its declaration like $("jpgLink0") $("jpgLink1") etc?

Comment: @Mark: I got it working!  Give me a minute to update the answer.

Comment: @Rocket  THATS IT!  Thanks so much for your help!  I had to pass the contractId['contract'] var to the constructor too but that did the trick! Thank you so much for your help you saved my neck!!!

Comment: @Mark: You're welcome!  I've had this issue before as well, just forgot how I fixed it.  Had to look at my old code to remember.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for each of the 3 conditions:

-1

```
for (var page=(contractId['pages']-1); page>=0; page--) {
    $("#jpgLinks").prepend("<span><a href='#' id='jpgLink"+page+"'><img src='img/JPG-Link_con-" + (page+1) + ".png' alt=''><br>Page " + (page+1) + "<\/a><\/span>");
    $('#jpgLink'+page).live('click', function() {
        showWorkingDialog();
        net.tsn.contract.log(contractId['contract'] + "-" + page, "DOWNLOAD_JPG", '<?php echo $_GET['lead']; ?>');
    });
}
```

0:

```
for (var page=(contractId['pages']-1); page>=0; page--) {
    $("#jpgLinks").prepend("<span><a href='#' id='jpgLink"+page+"'><img src='img/JPG-Link_con-" + (page+1) + ".png' alt=''><br>Page " + (page+1) + "<\/a><\/span>");
    var contractPage = contractId['contract'] + "-" + page;
    $('#jpgLink'+page).live('click', function() {
        showWorkingDialog();
        net.tsn.contract.log(contractPage, "DOWNLOAD_JPG", '<?php echo $_GET['lead']; ?>');
    });
}
```

and [object Object]:

```
for (var page=(contractId['pages']-1); page>=0; page--) {
    $("#jpgLinks").prepend("<span><a href='#' id='jpgLink"+page+"'><img src='img/JPG-Link_con-" + (page+1) + ".png' alt=''><br>Page " + (page+1) + "<\/a><\/span>");
    $('#jpgLink'+page).live('click', function(page) {
        showWorkingDialog();
        net.tsn.contract.log(contractId['contract'] + "-" + page, "DOWNLOAD_JPG", '<?php echo $_GET['lead']; ?>');
    });
}
```

Comment: You should have added this to the question, not as an answer.  Also, in the 3rd block, you cannot pass variables like that.  When an event is triggered, jQuery passes the event data to the function, if you put a variable there.  In the 3rd code block, `page` is the jQuery `event` object.

Comment: ok.. makes sense on #3 why I'm getting an object retunred, I was in a hurry to post those 3 cases so I appologize for adding it as an answer. will be careful in the future

Comment: It's ok, I just thought I'd let you know.